# Unable to animate the character in unity3d

Tags: c#, animation, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity3d.
I was following Unity Official Tutorial Series(https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character?playlist=17144)

They did it on Unity 4

I used the same script..

But i think it's the problem in animator panel.

I mean when i run the app it starts animating according to the following order

[image: Inspector]

On the above image under the setting option it shows idle then move..
According to it when i click on start game it shows idle animation for some sec them move for few second..

I am using the same assets they were using..

So help me... OMG I am so NOOB

[image: Animator screen]

Comment: It is quite possible that they used a certain parameter to switch between the *idle* and the *move* animations. You need to define a transition for this animation to happen. Also, it would make sense to share your Animator screen here.

Comment: I declared parameter too @SlashG and wait another screenshot is coming

Comment: updated @SlashG .......

Comment: I'm not too experienced with Animator myself. Maybe it has something to do with **Has Exit Time**, I guess it shouldn't be enabled if you have a parameter based transition.

Comment: And it worked @SlashG THanx for the help xD

Comment: I'll put it down as an answer then. Accept it maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because you have **Has Exit Time** enabled. This flag should be unchecked if you want to use a (solely) parameter based transition.